# Entity Framework Core throwing exception about unrelated EF6 context

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have a slightly unconventional project which uses both EF Core 3.1 and EF6. EF Core is used for the application's main database, and EF6 is used for a (legacy) identity database. The project is written in .NET Framework 4.8 and uses Microsoft.AspNet.Identity for the identity functionality. The application is an MVC Web project.

I have configured an EF Core DbContext, and set up the DbSets and model, however when I attempt to use any of the EF Core DbSets to get data from the database it complains that one of the DbSets from the EF6 context is misconfigured.

It's not entirely clear to me how EF Core even knows about this other context or its DbSets. If I had to guess I would assume that Microsoft.AspNet.Identity is trying to be clever and adding its DbSets to some sort of global/common variable somewhere and EF Core is picking them up from there.

From what I can tell I can use EF6 and EF Core in the same application, so I don't think this is a compatibility issue with these libraries https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/side-by-side. Additionally EF Core is supported by .NET Framework https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/platforms

I'm unsure if the older Microsoft.AspNet.Identity (not Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity) is compatible with EF Core, but if it is I would be willing to upgrade that and remove EF6 entirely, however the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework NuGet package has a dependency on EF6, so I suspect not.

I can provide code samples if required, but there are so many pieces to this application that I wouldn't even know where to begin.

Thanks

Edit:

The exception I am getting is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'ClassFromEF6Context' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.'

However I shouldn't have to define this entity as `HasNoKey()` as it is part of a different, unrelated context.

Edit 2:

It seems that `modelBuilder.Ignore<ClassFromEF6Context>();` can be used to mask the issue. I'm willing to keep troubleshooting, and I will continue to look for a nicer solution, but at least I am able to proceed with this workaround

Comment: Can you please provide the full error text?

Comment: @GuruStron `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'ClassFromEF6Context' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.'` I haven't added this 'ClassFromEF6Context' to the EF Core context, so I'm not sure how EF Core even knows that it exists

Comment: Can you please add your Core context?

Comment: Has `ClassFromEF6Context` been identified by convention? Does one of your entity types have a property of that class that you haven't ignored?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Nope, I looked through all of my entities and none of them have ClassFromEF6Context as a property. I was able to suppress the error using `modelBuilder.Ignore<ClassFromEF6Context>();` however I am surprised it is picking up the class in the first place, it is part of a different namespace and the `OnModelCreating` method for the EF6 context hadn't even been called yet. I suspect it has to be MS Identity doing something in the background to expose it to EF 6 and EF Core is picking up on it

Comment: You could debug the contents of `modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()` in various places in your `OnModelCreating`, maybe that will help narrow down where it's being defined.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman A good idea, but unfortunately no luck, even when placed right at the top of `OnModelCreating` all 67 EntityTypes are there, including 4 (ClassFromEF6Context and 3 others) from the EF6 context.

Comment: So the entity must be added by a convention during initialisation. If you replaced the `IConventionSetBuilder`, you could probably add a hook on the `OnEntityTypeAdded` event to work out exactly where this is coming from. (src here https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/v5.0.7/src/EFCore/Metadata/Internal/Model.cs#L272). Probably not worth the effort though.

Comment: I've had that error in the past but only when a class in my dbset does not have the [Key] attribute set for the Id of the class.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `DvContext`s and `DbSet`s, but classes referenced by other classes included in the model - [Including types in the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#including-types-in-the-model): *"as are any types that are found by recursively exploring the navigation properties of other discovered entity types"*. So you definitely has reference (either directly or via collection) to your EF6 class in some of the classes used by EF Core context. Use "Find All References" command in VS or similar to find it.

Comment: @IvanStoev I think this might be it, I just found a class in the EF Core model that is inheriting from one of the EF6 classes (not sure why...). I suspect that this EF6 class probably has a relationship with the `ClassFromEF6Context` and that's how it got introduced into the EF Core model. I'll do some digging and report back if that's the case